# Angular - Setup a service's function to a function call with specific parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a "service" in AngularJS (using `.factory()`, actually). In it, I declare and return an `exports` object, which will serve as the interface with whichever component injects the service, like so:

```
angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('exampleService', exampleService);

function exampleService() {
    var exports = {
        serviceFunction : serviceFunction
    };

    return exports;

    function serviceFunction(arg) {...};
}
```

What I would like to do is to declare an attribute in `exports` to behave as a function call to a service function with a predetermined argument. The idea would be something like:

```
var exports = {
    serviceFunction : serviceFunction,
    someOtherFunction : serviceFunction('specific value')
};

//later calling it like so
exampleService.someOtherFunction();
```

However, the function would be evaluated and `someOtherFunction` would be the returned value instead of a function call, right?

Is there any way to achieve this, **besides creating a function that returns the desired function call**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way how to assign a delegate to a function call in ES5. Simply wrap serviceFunction to another function returning function:

```
function serviceFunctionWrap() {
 return function() {
  return serviceFunction('specific value');
 }
}
```

Then

```
var exports = {
    serviceFunction : serviceFunction,
    someOtherFunction : serviceFunctionWrap()
};
```

Or do it inline:

```
var exports = {
    serviceFunction : serviceFunction,
    someOtherFunction : (function () {
      return serviceFunction('specific value');
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess there's no way around it then... Inline it is then!

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = {
 funcOne : function(a){
   alert(a);
 }, 
 funcTwo : function(a){
  this.funcOne(a);
 },
}

x.funcTwo("hi"); // will launch first function passing it "hi" as argument;
```